# `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] relation "XXX.XXX" does not exist` on production mode with NestJS + TypeORM + Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, typeorm

Below Nest.js + Postgres + TypeORM setup works fine during development building mode and local environment:

```js
import MemberModel from "@DataBase/Models/MemberModel";
import MemberTypeORM_Gateway from "@DataBase/Gateways/MemberTypeORM_Gateway";
import MemberController from "./Controllers/MemberController";
import { Module as NestJS_Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModule as TypeORM_Module } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import type { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";


@NestJS_Module({

  imports: [

    TypeORM_Module.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
        type: "postgres",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 5432,
        username: "postgres",
        password: "pass1234"
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true
      })
    }),

    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ MemberModel ])

  ],

  controllers: [
    MemberController
  ],

  providers: [
    {
      provide: "MemberGateway",
      useClass: MemberTypeORM_Gateway
    }
  ]

})
export default class NestJS_ApplicationRootModule {}
```

Herewith, the `docker-compose.yml` file for the local environment is:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: LocalDatabase
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass1234

    volumes:
      - DataBaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  DataBaseData:
    driver: local
```

The production setup has below differences:

```js
@NestJS_Module({

  imports: [

    TypeORM_Module.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
        type: "postgres",
        host: "database", // instead of "localhost"
        port: 5432,
        username: "postgres",
        password: "pass1234"
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: false // instead of "true"
      })
    }),

    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ MemberModel ])

  ],

  // ...

})
export default class NestJS_ApplicationRootModule {}
```

Herewith the `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  node_js:

    container_name: FrontServer
    build: .
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]
    depends_on: [ "database" ]


  database:

    container_name: Database

    image: postgres
    ports: [ "5432:5432" ]

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass1234

    volumes:
      - Database:/data/new.jiseikan.jp

volumes:
  Database: {}
```

When I try get some `member` entities, I get the error:

```
 [Nest] 1  - 12/10/2022, 4:23:03 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] relation "members.members" does not exist
 QueryFailedError: relation "members.members" does not exist
     at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/var/www/example.com/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:211:19)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
     at async SelectQueryBuilder.loadRawResults (/var/www/example.com/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.js:2028:25)
     at async SelectQueryBuilder.executeEntitiesAndRawResults (/var/www/example.com/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.js:1888:26)
     at async SelectQueryBuilder.getRawAndEntities (/var/www/example.com/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.js:638:29)
     at async SelectQueryBuilder.getMany (/var/www/example.com/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.js:704:25)
     at async B.retrieveAndSortByType (/var/www/example.com/FrontServerEntryPoint.js:1:21266)
     at async /var/www/example.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
     at async /var/www/example.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Let me repeat that it occurs during production mode only.

Of course, I have checked the similar question.
One solution was set `synchronize` to `true`.
However, the NestJS developers has warned do not do it at production mode.

> Setting synchronize: true shouldn't be used in production - otherwise you can lose production data.
> [NestJS Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)

Anyway, I'll tried it and nothing changed.

### Additional listings

#### MemberModel

The NestJS developer calls it "entity" however according the Clean Architecture, "The entities (enterprise business rules) must depends on nothing" while below class depends on TypeORM. So, the "Member" entity will be at next listing.

```js
import Member from "@EnterpriseBusinessRules/Members/Member";
import WinLossRecords from "@EnterpriseBusinessRules/Members/WinLossRecords";

import {
  Entity as TypeORM_Entity,
  Column as DatabaseColumn,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn
} from "typeorm";


@TypeORM_Entity({ name: MemberModel.DATA_BASE_TABLE_NAME })
export default class MemberModel implements Member {

  public static readonly DATA_BASE_TABLE_NAME: string = "members";

  private static readonly defaultWinLossRecordsValue: WinLossRecords = {
    wins: 0, knockouts: 0, losses: 0, draws: 0, totalBattles: 0
  };


  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  public readonly ID!: Member.ID;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "varchar",
    nullable: !Member.DisplayingName.REQUIRED,
    length: Member.DisplayingName.MAXIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT
  })
  public readonly displayingName!: string;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "text",
    nullable: !Member.AvatarURI.REQUIRED
  })
  public readonly avatarURI!: string;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "text",
    nullable: !Member.LargePhotoURI.REQUIRED
  })
  public readonly largePhotoURI!: string;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "enum",
    enum: Object.values(Member.Types),
    nullable: !Member.Type.REQUIRED
  })
  public readonly type!: Member.Types;


  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "simple-json",
    default: MemberModel.defaultWinLossRecordsValue
  })
  public readonly domesticWinLossRecords!: WinLossRecords;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "simple-json",
    default: MemberModel.defaultWinLossRecordsValue
  })
  public readonly overseasWinLossRecords!: WinLossRecords;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "simple-json",
    default: MemberModel.defaultWinLossRecordsValue
  })
  public readonly amateurWinLossRecords!: WinLossRecords;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "simple-array",
    nullable: !Member.Ranks.REQUIRED
  })
  public readonly ranks?: Array<string>;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "date",
    nullable: !Member.BirthDate__ISO8601.REQUIRED
  })
  public readonly birthDate__ISO8601?: string;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "varchar",
    nullable: !Member.Birthplace.REQUIRED,
    length: Member.Birthplace.MAXIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT
  })
  public readonly birthplace!: string;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "simple-array",
    nullable: !Member.MessageSplitToParagraphs.REQUIRED
  })
  public readonly messageSplitToParagraphs?: Array<string>;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "text",
    nullable: !Member.PersonalBlogURI.REQUIRED
  })
  public readonly personalBlogURI!: string;

  @DatabaseColumn({
    type: "simple-json",
    default: {}
  })
  public readonly socialNetworkProfilesURIs!: Member.SocialNetworkProfilesURIs;
}
```

### Member

```js
import type WinLossRecords from "./WinLossRecords";


type Member = {

  ID: Member.ID;
  displayingName: string;
  avatarURI: string;
  largePhotoURI: string;
  type: Member.Types;

  domesticWinLossRecords: WinLossRecords;
  overseasWinLossRecords: WinLossRecords;
  amateurWinLossRecords: WinLossRecords;

  ranks?: Array<string>;
  birthDate__ISO8601?: string;
  birthplace?: string;
  messageSplitToParagraphs?: Array<string>;
  personalBlogURI?: string;
  socialNetworkProfilesURIs: Member.SocialNetworkProfilesURIs;
};


namespace Member {

  export type ID = string;
  export namespace ID {

    export const TYPE: StringConstructor = String;
    export const REQUIRED: boolean = true;
    export const MAXIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT: number = 1;

    export function isValid(potentialID: unknown): potentialID is ID {
      return typeof potentialID === "string" && potentialID.length >= MAXIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT;
    }
  }

  export namespace DisplayingName {
    export const TYPE: StringConstructor = String;
    export const REQUIRED: boolean = true;
    export const MINIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT: number = 1;
    export const MAXIMAL_CHARACTERS_COUNT: number = 255;
  }

  // And so on.

}


export default Member;
```

### Update: newest conditional preset

What I don't like is the **MemberModel** has been set twice: at `entities` property and also at `TypeOrmModule.forFeature`. Can I safely leave just one of?

```js
@NestJS_Module({

  imports: [

    TypeORM_Module.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({

        type: "postgres",
        host: ConfigurationRepresentative.isLocalExecutionEnvironment ? "localhost" : "database",
        port: 5432,
        username: "postgres",
        password: "pass1234"

        autoLoadEntities: ConfigurationRepresentative.isLocalExecutionEnvironment,

        ...ConfigurationRepresentative.isLocalExecutionEnvironment ? null : { entities: [ MemberModel ] },

        synchronize: ConfigurationRepresentative.isLocalExecutionEnvironment

      })
    }),

    // Duplicate?
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ MemberModel ])

  ]

  // ...

})
export default class NestJS_ApplicationRootModule {}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the autoLoadEntities option to false in your TypeOrmModuleOptions? This will tell TypeORM to not automatically load entities from the given connection, and you will need to manually specify which entities you want to use in your application by passing them to the TypeOrmModule.forFeature method. I'm talking it because this error may appear when entities from one connection are not present in another connection.

Comment: @JulienAmbrosio Thank you for the comment. I have tried to set `autoLoadEntities` to `false` but it does not work. However, the error message has changed. Previously, was "relation 'members.members' does not exist", but now it is "relation 'members' does not exist". I have appended the newest preset to the end of the question (**Update: newest conditional preset** section), would you please to take a look?  What I don't like is the `MemberModel` has been set twice: at `entities` property and also at `TypeOrmModule.forFeature`.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting path to your entities in your TypeOrm config based on environment? I'd assume NestJS can't find them after project is built into dist folder, but I could be wrong, just something from a top of my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your production database is not identical to your development database.

Note that **synchronize**, which you define as **true** in development, automatically performs migrations so that your database is identical to your modeling.

Once you disable this, it is up to the developer or DBA to manually create a migration to update the database.

Using [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.com/download), you can easily compare two databases and see the difference between them. I suggest you do this on your development and production bench.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does [NestsJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) give the instructions how to migrate is on production mode? Or just tells: "`synchronize: true` shouldn't be used in production - otherwise you can lose production data."

Comment: This is the responsibility of the ORM, in your case the TypeORM.
Here is the [link](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/migrations) to the migration documentation.